# MVC outputcache not caching in server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I thought this would be a simple thing but it's driving me nuts.  I simply added the following...

`[OutputCache(Duration = 300)]`

before an action

`public ViewResult Index(string parameter) {...}`

But it's not caching it, I put a breakpoint in the debugger inside the action and it hits it every time I go to that page. It does work if I set the `Location` parameter to `Client` but I want it to be server based.  Do I have to enable caching somewhere else for it to work?

Comment: if it matters, the `parameter` comes from the router, as in `routes.MapRoute(null, "{parameter}", new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "index" })`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the problem. The Base controller set a cookie in `OnActionExecuting`, and I found out that a page that sets a cookie doesn't get stored in the output cache, so basically pages were not being cached regardless of the `[OutputCache]` directive.

Comment: What did you do to solve your issue? Did you keep the action filter and if so did you still pursue caching?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved this problem by fixing the exact parameter at the argument **VaryByParam**.

```
[OutputCache(Duration=120, VaryByParam ="argument1")]
```

Do this instead of **VaryByParam ="*"**

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue in my project and find out a solution.
In BaseController (It may be a generic controller though), Some others developer added an attribute [DisableCache] to disable cache and after removing that attribute from base controller, [OutputCache] worked fine.

```
    //[DisableCache]
    public class BaseController : Controller
    { 
    }
  
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.Any,Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public ActionResult GetIntegratedModules()
    {
        var applications = cacheManagerService.GetAllAspNetApplications();

        var model = new IntegratedModuleListViewModel
        {
            Applications = applications
        };

        return PartialView("_IntegratedModulesPartial", model);
    }
```

Hope this clue will helpful for others. Thanks!